# Ruby On Rails map 2 database columns to 2D JSON array

Tags: json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to grab two columns of data out of a database, using Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord calls and put them into a 2D JSON array for passing to the client.

I have it working for one column. Now I need to get it working for 2 columns.

This is what I have so far for the database call:

```
select("TOTAL").map{|x| x.TOTAL.ceil}
```

This is what I have for the controller:

```
@results = JSON.dump({ :totals => PerformanceResults.find_totals })
```

This gives me something like this:
    {"totals"    [145,132,863,693,372,74,838,91,18,172,84,90,373,161,160,173,1910,210,513,14,79,21,84,41,2630,0,93,150,2971]}

To get two columns, this is how I'm starting out, but it's not going well:

Database call:

```
select("TOTAL, time_stamp ").map{|x| x.attributes.slice(:x.TOTAL.ceil, x.time_stamp)}
```

Its telling me "undefined method `TOTAL' for :x:Symbol", which I understand, but since I'm new to Ruby on Rails and also JSON, I thought I'd ask for some help in doing this...

My goal is to get this passed to the client: {"totals"    [['timestamp', data], ['timestamp', data], etc.... ]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this on my own using the following for anyone looking for this solution in the future.

```
select("TOTAL, time_stamp ").map{|x| [x.TOTAL.ceil, x.time_stamp]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails console, to fetch multiple columns, you could also use the following method. Suppose you have a User table and you wish to print the id's and email's of the users, You have to do it as shown below:

```
User.all.map{|user| "#{user.id},#{user.email}"}
```

This is an alternative to what was already explained above.